# How to send many messages in one go with MQ Visual Edit?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq-visual-edit

I’m using MQ Visual Edit V3 to inject financial messages in a queue.

I’m able to inject one message but not several messages.

The separator I use is `\n`. 1 message = 1 row

But when I inject several messages only one is put in the queue and the content is the concatenation of all the messages.

Can you explain me how to send many messages in one go please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the ***Import File*** window, use ***Every line of each file*** option rather than using the '\n' delimiter.

[image]

Currently, the ***Import File*** window does not support '\n' delimiter.  I'll add it to the user request list.

MQ Visual Edit does support explicitly using HEX values for CRLF or LF i.e. 0D0A or 0A in the Delimiter field.  Just remember to select ***Delimited File*** and then  ***Hexadecimal Delimiter***